# Only run a task when another task finishes successfully

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a task which implements the following:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task createEntity = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        await _clearerStagingService.SaveNewClearer(clearerStaging);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cancelToken.Cancel();
        Logger.SendError($"Failed to save", ex);
    }
}, cancelToken.Token);
```

As you can see, the cancellation token is called when an error occurs. This is because I want the thread to exit upon failing - is this the correct way to safely exit a thread upon fail?

I then implemented the following code, which should only run when the above thread is run successfully:

```
createEntity.Wait(cancelToken.Token);

if (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await _auditService.CreateAudit(audit);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.SendError("Could not create Audit.", ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm unsure if this is the way to implement cancel tokens, I tried looking around but was quite confused.

Some help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm are you sure you want to use `Task` here? Why not just `await _clearerStagingService.SaveNewClearer(clearerStaging); await _auditService.CreateAudit(audit);`? This smells a little of you trying to run async code in a synchronous method

Comment: @Liam this is because I am using WPF, the code here is within the ViewModel

Comment: Once you're using `async`/`await`, you should only really be thinking about `Task.Run` if you're wanting to launch a *CPU* bound task. Otherwise find a way for `async`/`await` to find a way into all of your code - which may in *certain* circumstances mean you end up writing `async void` methods (for events. Just make sure you install a handler for unobserved exceptions). Once you're just using `await`, that is precisely how you write code that continues once the previous task has completed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is a little contrived. However, Let `async` be `async`

These methods don't take a cancellation token, so there is no advantage to having one (seemingly) in your situation. Would this not work?

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{    
    await _clearerStagingService.SaveNewClearer(clearerStaging);
    await _auditService.CreateAudit(audit);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Now that I think of it, this should've hit me as the most obvious solution. Not sure why I went to create two seperate tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        await _clearerStagingService.SaveNewClearer(clearerStaging);
        await _auditService.CreateAudit(audit);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
});
```

if `SaveNewClearer` throws an exception then `CreateAudit` **won't run** and `CreateAudit` **will run** after `CreateAudit`. `await` will "pause" the task when the `async` operation happens and then resume the task when it returns at the same place it was paused.

If anything fails the `Task` will end naturally without any cancellation tokens.

I'm not convinced you need the `Task.Run()` TBH but I don't know WPF so I'm presuming there is a good reason for this, not blocking the UI thread maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As per Liam's answer, you not need to create separate tasks every time for each statement 
when you already call task to wait via `createEntity.Wait(cancelToken.Token);`

```
try
    {
        await _clearerStagingService.SaveNewClearer(clearerStaging);
        await _auditService.CreateAudit(audit);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

**Also I would like to add about CancellationTokenSource**

You only need `CancellationTokenSource` when you want to cancel task explicitly otherwise no need to use `CancellationTokenSource.Token`

Comment: I've done this but for some reason the program hangs upon exiting the application (pressing x button) when I intentionally cause it to throw an exception